# Data security in selenium

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

How does selenium impose security in remote grid calls?

I have a test service in one machine. The grid is in another remote machine. This is simple buy a product flow:

1) Test service invokes my website on remote grid browser.
2) For the credit card field in checkout , the service sends the credit card data that is stored securely in it to the remote browser.
3) The service then calls the submit button on the remote browser to submit the data to the website.

How does selenium handle the data flow in step 2? Is there any way to encrypt the data in transit?

Comment: Can you expand on your question? The browser will act like any other browser, running on the GRID server or not.

Comment: Thanks Jamie. I understand the browser behaves as a normal browser. But is there a data encryption when the service send the credit card details to the remote grid to be populated in the browser field ?

Comment: Do you mean from your code to the GRID server? How is it sent?

Comment: yes. thats correct .. i call the remote grid from my service code . is there a way to encrypt the data in the transit?

Comment: I do not think so, you could create a secure VPN between the code and the GRID server

Comment: Thanks Jamie. My code lies in a prod server box and I am not sure if we have the control for setting the secure connection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73199/discussion-between-stackuser-and-jamie-rees).

Comment: i notice that when selenium opens on my computer the chrome automation extension populates on my chrome and it has permission to read my browser history. does this mean all the data passed to my code from the selenium browser is collected and stored by this extension?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is a browser automation library. It does not have any capability of encrypting anything anywhere anytime. If you need encryption, there are other libraries in the Java world (or whichever binding you are using) that accomplish that task.

As for in-transit encryption for communication between node and hub, that is entirely up to the communication channel. Again, Selenium does not encrypt anything. There are various networking solution for securing communication traffic.

Lastly. Selenium is generally used in a testing situation, where you are hopefully talking to test servers and never using live data with real information (such as live user passwords, live credit cards, etc.) In this case, there is no need to encrypt any of this *made up* data, because even if it leaks out, it will be meaningless in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a ssh tunnel to local port on your host and encrypt connection to nodes with ssh this way.